# Windows Phone 8 (WP8) ScrollViewer with non scrollable WebBrowser Control Inside

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, scroll, webbrowser-control

Ich have a WP8 XAML project and on one page I have the following XAML structure:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="12,17,0,17">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Article.Title}"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
                   Margin="12,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Article.LastUpdateDate}"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
                   Margin="12,0" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ScrollViewer">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

The StackPanel is used to display different content. Letzt Say some Images, a webbrowser control and some more images.

The height of my Webbrowser Control fits the content height. So I don't want to scroll inside the Webbrowser Control. I followed this article to do that:
http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/11/17/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control.html

So I check for scrolling event and ignore that:

```
        private void Border_ManipulationDelta(object sender,
                                          ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        // suppress zoom
        if (e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X != 0.0 ||
            e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y != 0.0)
            e.Handled = true;

        // optionally suppress scrolling
        if (ScrollDisabled)
        {
            if (e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X != 0.0 ||
              e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y != 0.0)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is working fine so far, but if the focus is on my webbrowser control iand I try to scroll, the webbrowser is not scrolling, but I would like to scroll the parent scrollviewer instead.

Is there a possibility to push that event up to the scrollviewer.

Or is ther another possibility to just disable scrolling in my control, but always be abel scrolling my scrollviewer?

Best regards,

Mike.

Comment: Have you tried setting IsHitTestVisible="False" on the WebBrowser?

Comment: Hey William.
I tried this, the scrolling behaviour is the exactly what I would like to have. But the issue I have  - in this case I am not able to use links or mark text anymore and tha is what I need....

Comment: If you don't care about having a 'hard' height value, you can perhaps try http://www.geekchamp.com/forums/windows-phone-development/how-to-disable-webbrowser-scrolling-in-wp8